# Preferred method to reload page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reload

which way to reload a current page (using a button) would you prefer?

```
1 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="history.go(0)">
2 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="location.reload(true)">
3 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="window.location.reload(true)">
4 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
5 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
6 <input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="document.location.href=document.location.href">
```

As the URL of the page changes frequently AFAIK a 'fallback function' like

```
<a href="urlOfCurrentPage.html" onclick="window.location.reload(true);return false;">Reload</a>
```

won't work for me, right?

Comment: Note that numbers 2 and 3 are the same thing

Comment: Number 4 and 6 will not reload anything if there is a # present in the url

Comment: Number 2, 3 & 5 aren't implemented by all browsers, use `*.location.reload()` as the argument is only used to specify if the cache should be ignored. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876244/browser-support-for-window-location-reloadtrue

Comment: OP missed the most preferred method of all: location.reload();

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. The fourth and sixth methods there won't reload any form data, they essentially make a separate visit to the page. Some versions of Firefox also have issues with the third method. Other than that, I'd go with the fifth as a personal preference. It seems the clearest.

Comment: The second method (.reload) is not work in some cases.

Comment: so, "document.location.reload(true)" is cross-browser secure and the most robust one?

Comment: @Mel, I believe so. Really, window and document should both work.

Comment: note that when you use document.location.reload() on a POST the browser will ask you if you want resend the data to reload the page.

Comment: Wimmel, yes to fix that use the PRG pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 30):

You may also do:

`wd` represents **window** || **document**:

- **wd.location.assign(wd.location.href)** : 
  *go to the URL*
- **wd.location.replace(wd.location.href)** :
  *go to the URL and replace previous page in history*
- **wd.location.reload(<true/false/blank>)** : *reload page from server/cache/cache*