# Browser support for window.location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, browser-support

`window.location.reload()` is supported in all browsers, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

But what's with `window.location.reload(true)` which reloads the page without cache? How well is it supported?

Comment: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: window.location.reload(true);   // reload page with server post back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location.reload()` takes no arguments in the [specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location), so do not rely on it. It is implemented in some browsers though, including [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: I believe the correct answer to the question is a LIST of those browsers that support the extra boolean parameter.  Simply saying that Firefox supports it is not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 5):

`reload()` is supposed to accept an argument which tells it to do a hard reload, ie, ignoring the cache:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Note : I don`t think just saying that it is supported with FF is right, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722855/1877909) it is clearly mentioned that it is supported by other browser as well.

**Check out below links for more information**

[how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

[Reload without cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722855/1877909)

[Location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload)

[Reload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[refresh-reload-page-using-jquery](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/03/refresh-reload-page-using-jquery.htm)

[Is Window.location.reload(true)?](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8db6dd9b-16de-45d1-a6c9-8a04df0073bd/is-windowlocationreloadtrue?forum=crmdevelopment)

**Little Extra information in this question**

[difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Hope this helps