# How to showing alert in ajax with refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to send alert Error.
I wrote this code:

```
function doSomthing(){

    var x= $("#MyText").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myUrl",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
    Text : tParm },
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
        location.reload(true);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Message");
        location.reload(true);
    }
    }); 
}
```

I want that when I get error:
1. Doing refresh. working! (`location.reload(true);`)
2. Showing alert error. not working! (`alert("This Item is not Exist");`).

what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe it's not going to the error function, it's reloading in the success function. Try alert in the success to make sure where the reload is being called.

Comment: It's not working also in the success function.
I get this: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: You need to know about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876244/browser-support-for-window-location-reloadtrue) especially the last answer