# Refresh page in symfony2 at the end of Ajax call

Tags: ajax, symfony

How can I refresh a page after an ajax call is executed. 
My Ajax call is

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patents_trashpatents') }}",
         cache: false
});
```

The method that is executed by this ajax is

```
 public function trashpatentAction(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $patent_id = $request->get("pid");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $patent = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:SvPatents')->find($patent_id);
        if (!$patent) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No patent found for id '.$patent_id);
        }
        $patent->setIs_deleted(1);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Portfolio Controller Index Action

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
     $switch_form = $this->createForm(new SwitchPortfolioType($portfolios));
     ////rest of action code
     return $this->render('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig', array('new_patentgroup_form' => $new_patentgroup_form->createView(),'switch_form' => $switch_form->createView(), 'new_form' => $new_form->createView(), "portfolios" => $portfolios ,"selected_portfolio" => $selected_portfolio,"portfolio_groups" => $portfolio_groups,"patents" => $patents));

}
```

Index.html.twig

```
 <form name="portfolios" action="{{ path('v2_pm_portfolio') }}" method="post" >
            {{ form_widget(switch_form) }}
            <input type="submit"class="portfolio_input button2 tooltip" value="Switch">
 </form>
```

SwitchPortfolioType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class SwitchPortfolioType extends AbstractType
{
public function __construct($portfolios)
{
    $this->portfolios = $portfolios;
}


public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
                'test' => 'Test'
        ),
            'empty_value' => 'Switch your Portfolio',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'switch_portfolio';
}
```

}

At the end of this action I want to refresh the page

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The refresh will have to be done in javascript. I am not sure why you would POST via ajax only to reload the page anyway, why not just POST normally?

Anyway, to do what you ask I would return some simple JSON response in the controller to signify a success and then in the ajax callback do this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patents_trashpatents') }}",
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
         // optionally check if the response is what you wanted
         //if (data.response == 'deleted') {
             document.location.reload(true);
         //}
     }
});
```

Comment: I've edited my post to change the reload function. Seems this one should be more universally acceptable to reloading the page. from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript

Comment: it says Variable &quot;switch_form&quot; does not exist in &quot;MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig&quot;

Comment: That's unrelated. That means you're trying to use a variable in twig that was not passed in via the controller.

Comment: I would need to see more code from the controller action and the twig template to guess why it's not visible.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQUery:**

```
$('your_form').disable=true;
```

**Pure JS:**

```
your_form.disabled = true;
```

Comment: jQuery: `$('your_form').prop("disabled", true);` or mix `$('your_form')[0].disable=true;`