# FB.login(function(response) when page is refreshed /me doesn't update

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a big problem that I tried to fix for days now without being able.

I got the following code to Log in an aplication on Facebook. Everything is working well except that when the page is reloading (with window.location.reload();) it is not updating API /me so it always coming back with the login button.

EXCEPTION: when I click F5 to refresh the page then it is working well

If someone could help that would be appreciated

Thanks

```
 <?php

require 'facebook.php';

 // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

 // login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 } else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
 }

 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 // Session based API call.
if ($user) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
     $user = null;
}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
 <title>test full name and photo</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>', // App ID
        channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
      window.location.reload();
    });

};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

 function fbLogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
                window.location.reload();            }
      else {
        alert('Try to connect');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
    }
  </script>




<?php if ($user): ?>
USER LOGGIN

<?php else: ?>
<div>
 Connexion button: <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ONCLICK="fbLogin()" value="login">
</div>
<?php endif ?>


<?php if ($user): ?>
    <?php $uid = $me['id']; ?>
    <div align="center">
        <img id="image" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $uid; ?>/picture" />
        <div id="name"><?php echo $me['name']; ?></div>
        <div id="name">UID: <?php echo $me['id']; ?></div>
        <div id="name">Courriel <?php echo $me['email']; ?></div>

    </div>
<?php endif ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try window.location.reload( true ); ?

Comment: Yes, without any changes

Comment: Did you try any other alternatives such as:
document.location.reload( true ); ?
Here is a page with some other alternitives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript

Comment: I just tried document.location.reload( true ); without any changes but as I mentionned the page IS reloading but it keep /me as "NULL"

Comment: I tried to redirect to an other page but again /me is not updated on that new page

Comment: Sorry I misread. When you say /me is not updated do you mean $me?

Comment: Yeah, 
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
So it is like user is not yet connected to the application but after pressing F5 to refresh it is ok.

Comment: And this is only after Fb_login. Once logged in, if you quit and come back to the application it works fine

Comment: Id check the documentation and see if it says anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

`FB.login` does **not** return `response.status`, this is returned by [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/). Please also refer to the [`FB.login` document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look to it.


My site:
[Concours Quebec](http://www.concoursduquebec.com/index.php)