# How can I recreate the reload issue when a button is pressed on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I had an issue with my company's Web product, when a button is pressed the whole page is reloaded. This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page), I tried the solution and it works.

Now I need to confirm the behavior on the versions of Internet Explorer that does not run on Windows XP (but some of our clients uses). All of the PC in my office still runs Windows XP, and with strict policy there's no way I can use my home PC or laptop to access that product.

I've tried to recreate the issue by creating a small HTML codes containing a button. However the refreshing does not occur. I missed some criteria, and I don't know what it is. So I'd like ask what is required to makes it reload the page when a button is pressed. The button on the page is constructed using `<button>` tag.

Comment: If I've understood correctly your problem, only you need to do to reproduce the issue, is to add the `button` element (without any `type` attribute) into a `form`.

Comment: @Teemu, you're are correct. Also I tried put `<button>` tag inside `<form>` and the issue shows up. This is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'd like ask what is required to makes it reload the page when a
>   button is pressed

This should work in older browsers, too:

```
<button onclick="location.reload(true);">reload</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not really the case. The issue I found is the `onclick` handler does not reload the page. Still after the button is pressed the page reload itself.

Comment: from my understanding it should do exactly that. updaed the answer with the force-reload=true parameter. further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript