# how to check the aws s3 url is valid or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, url, request

I need to check the AWS s3 URL is valid or not using Nodejs, I need only the status code not all the data of the file
exa:-https://test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/occupancy.csv, I applied request method but it takes all the data from the file..second method AWS s3.headObject  but it only checks the bucket name exist or not 
tell me is there any method who give the status code that this URL has existed or not

Comment: this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051393/node-js-how-to-check-status-of-a-url-within-a-http-request

Comment: already I used request method but it fetched all the data that I don't need

Comment: but status code vary based on what happens, if you want just validate: var url = require("url");
var result = url.parse('http://drive.google.com/0/23'); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931079/validating-a-url-in-node-js/55585593

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do an HTTP head request to check whether the url exist.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'HEAD',
  url: 'https://test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/occupancy.csv',
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Reference:
[Getting HTTP headers with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922842/getting-http-headers-with-node-js)

Comment: assuming the s3 url is publicly accessible

Comment: white using this method it won't give any status code

Comment: sorry for the late reply. updated the answer. it works, I have tested this myself