# How to do a HTTP head request in next.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I want to achieve the same done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835247/how-to-check-the-aws-s3-url-is-valid-or-not) but in next.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js provides methods to fetch data from a server and using them as props. I don't know whether you want to use it before rendering a page (like getServerSideProps) or when, for example, you click a button, but I suppose its the first case.

My personal preference when doing requests, is [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), so I will use it in this example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    // Here is where we make the request
    const result = await axios({
        method: 'HEAD', // here is where we declare that we want to use the HEAD method
        url: "your server url", // this is the url where we want to send the request
        headers: {} // if you want to add custom headers, you can do it here
    })

    // Here we are logging the result of the request
    console.log(result)
}
```

You can refer to the [next.js documentation on data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) and the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)

Have a great day and I hope you succeed on your projects