# AJAX not coming up a success even though its updating the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My php is updating the table but not refreshing in javascript have tried several different ways of doing this and nothing is working.
PHP

```
$sql = "UPDATE INTOXDM.ASTP_FORM SET SUPERVISOR_EID = '".$newSuper."' WHERE FORMID = '".$formId."'";
$row = $xdm->fetch($sql);

$return["color"] = $row['APPRENTICE_SIGNATURE'];

$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Javascipt

```
var data = {
    "formId": formID,
    "newSuper": newSuper
};
data = $.param(data);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "src/GetInfo.php", 
    data: data,
success: function() {
    location.reload();
}

});
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$return["json"] = json_encode($return);` and then echoing `json_encode($return);`?  Why encode the JSON twice?  That may be the error, JavaScript may be having trouble decoding the JSON.

Comment: You should add an `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }` function to your `$.ajax` to see what's going on.  Also, open your debugger's network tab and see *exactly* what PHP is echoing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by modifing the code like this:

```
var data = {
    "formId": formID,
    "newSuper": newSuper
};

// No need for serialization here, 
// the 'data' parameter of jQuery.ajax accepts JS object
// data = $.param(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", 
    url: "src/GetInfo.php", 
    data: data,

    // As suggested by Rocket Hazmat, try to add an error callback here
    error: function(jQueryXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Something went wrong " + errorMessage);
    },

    success: function(jsonResponse) {
        // Try to reference the location object from document/window
        // wd = document or window as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript
        // Also watch out, usually browsers require a user confirmation before reloading if the page contains POST data

        // One of these should be fine
        wd.location.assign(wd.location.href) : go to the URL
        wd.location.replace(wd.location.href) : go to the URL and replace previous page in history
        wd.location.reload(<true/false/blank>) : reload page from server/cache/cache
    }
});
```

Also, this might be a shot in the dark but the parameter `dataType` gave me problems sometime in the past, so if you are sure about the json returned by your php script, you could use the eval function to jsonify the response

```
$.ajax({
    ...

    // Remove data type
    // dataType: "json", 

    ...

    success: function(plainTextResponse) {
        // Eval response, NOT SAFE! But working
        var jsonResponse = eval('('+ plainTextResponse +')');

        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax is expecting `json` data and your php is sending malformed `json` string. Send a correct `json` string and your script will work fine.

Your php json_encode should be like this:

```
$data = json_encode($return);
echo $data;
```