# Is window.location.reload() or location.reload() better?

Tags: javascript, reload

I need to refresh the page using JavaScript. I tried both `window.location.reload()` and `location.reload()`. Both are working and reloading the page. Which one should I use?

Comment: They are the same thing

Comment: `window` is implicit. When left off, it's assumed.

Comment: This might help bro,
[click here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Comment: why not use `window.window.window.location.reload()`? it works too...

Comment: you never need to use window, unless to skip over a local of the same name. for some reason though, a lot of code uses it extraneously but consistently; using it with `location` is common, as is `opener()`, `open()`,   and `addEventListener()`...   `getAppliedStyle()` seems almost always use `window.` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

> The Location interface represents the location (URL) of the object it is linked to. Changes done on it are reflected on the object it relates to. Both the Document and Window interface have such a linked Location, accessible via Document.location and Window.location respectively.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

So... they are the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Andre has the succinct answer, by far. You may also find these related questions of use from a research perspective:

- [Preferred method to reload page with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript)
- [Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)