# reload current page with javascript when PHP script has finished

Tags: javascript, reload

I'm searching for a way to reload a page when the page itself was loaded completely.

Here's what I need this for:

- 1st call of the script (using webbrowser to open the PHP script) will make some parsing of content from database
- when PHP script is finished the script should be called again (by reloading the website), PHP script will select new data from database and parse this data and so on...

I know this is a 'quick&dirty' solution, but it fits the needs for me.

Comment: You'll need the PHP script to provide something to the page to indicate it's already processed the data (or whatever), otherwise you'll get into an infinite loop of reloading. For reloading a page using JavaScript; [that question has been asked and answered many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: The PHP server will not send anything back until after the PHP script has finished, afaik. So as soon as the browser starts showing the page, the PHP script *has* to have finished.